# Read and use attributes from XML file using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml-namespaces

I am working on scripting some data from the InDesign file and I am successfully able to write it as XML file while is like

```
<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 6.0-c004 79.164570, 2020/11/18-15:51:46        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
            xmlns:xmpTPg="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/t/pg/"
            xmlns:xmpGImg="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/g/img/"
            xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"
            xmlns:stEvt="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceEvent#"
            xmlns:stMfs="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ManifestItem#"
            xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#"
            xmlns:idPriv="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/InDesign/private"
            xmlns:xmpG="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/g/"
            xmlns:stFnt="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/Font#">
         <dc:format>application/x-indesign</dc:format>
         <xmp:CreateDate>2020-12-08T11:45:46+05:30</xmp:CreateDate>
         <xmp:MetadataDate>2020-12-22T12:13:16+05:30</xmp:MetadataDate>
         <xmp:ModifyDate>2020-12-22T12:13:16+05:30</xmp:ModifyDate>
         <xmp:CreatorTool>Adobe InDesign 16.1 (Windows)</xmp:CreatorTool>
         <xmp:PageInfo>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <xmpTPg:PageNumber>1</xmpTPg:PageNumber>
                  <xmpGImg:format>JPEG</xmpGImg:format>
                  <xmpGImg:width>256</xmpGImg:width>
                  <xmpGImg:height>256</xmpGImg:height>
                  <xmpGImg:image>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/7QAsUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNA+0AAAAAABAASAAAAAEA&#xA;AQBIAAAAAQAB/+4AE0Fkb2JlAGQAAAAAAQUAAklE/9sAhAAMCAgICAgMCAgMEAsLCxAUDg0NDhQY&#xA;EhMTExIYFBIUFBQUEhQUGx4eHhsUJCcnJyckMjU1NTI7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7AQ0LCxAOECIYGCIyKCEo&#xA;MjsyMjIyOzs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7OztAQEBAQDtAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQED/wAARCAEA&#xA;AI8DAREAAhEBAxEB/8QBQgAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAwABAgQFBgcICQoLAQABBQEBAQEBAQAA&#xA;AAAAAAABAAIDBAUGBwgJCgsQAAEEAQMCBAIFBwYIBQMMMwEAAhEDBCESMQVBUWETInGBMgYUkaGx&#xA;QiMkFVLBYjM0coLRQwclklPw4fFjczUWorKDJkSTVGRFwqN0NhfSVeJl8rOEw9N14/NGJ5SkhbSV&#xA;xNTk9KW1xdXl9VZmdoaWprbG1ub2N0dXZ3eHl6e3x9fn9xEAAgIBAgQEAwQFBgcHBgI7AQACEQMh&#xA;MRIEQVFhcSITBTKBkRShsUIjwVLR8DMkYuFygpJDUxVjczTxJQYWorKDByY1wtJEk1SjF2RFVTZ0&#xA;ZeLys4TD03Xj80aUpIW0lcTU5PSltcXV5fVWZnaGlqa2xtbm9ic3R1dnd4eXp7fH1+f3/9oADAMB&#xA;AAIRAxEAPwD1VJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSznNY0veQ1o5JMAISkIiykAk6IvtuH/p6v89v9&#xA;6i+84f34/aF/s5P3Sr7bh/6er/Pb/el95w/vx+0K9nJ+6VfbcP8A09X+e3+9L7zh/fj9oV7OT90q&#xA;+24f+nq/z2/3pfecP78ftCvZyfulX23D/wBPV/nt/vS+84f34/aFezk/dKvtuH/p6v8APb/el95w&#xA;/vx+0K9nJ+6VfbcP/T1f57f70vvOH9+P2hXs5P3SmUzGpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSU5P1sy7sH&#xA;6uZ+XjlrbaqS5heJaDI5CEsUco4ZbFdjkYyBD5rj5v8AjBy6K8nHZiPqtaHsdDBLTwdXLMyYfheO&#xA;RjIysebfieZkLFJPV/xj/wCixfuZ/wCSTeH4T3l+Kf6T4K9X/GP/AKLF+5n/AJJLh+E95fir+k+C&#xA;vV/xj/6LF+5n/kkuH4T3l+Kv6T4Liz/GQeKcX7mf+SS4fhPeX4q/pPgt6v8AjH/0WL9zP/JJcPwn&#xA;vL8Vf0nwV6v+Mf8A0WL9zP8AySXD8J7y/FX9J8H1xazmsXvDG7nTHkJ/Ikph9or/AJX+af7klK+0&#xA;1fyvH6J/uSUu25j3bWzPmCPypKZOeGtLiDABPbskpkkpSSlJKUkpwvrw0u+qXVGjk0Hkx3HinYzU&#xA;gmO7x/ROs9Ix+jYVF+dj1210Ma9jrGy0gcHVc/znKZ58xMiEqJ7OtiywEACW7+3+h/8Alhjf9ut/&#xA;vVf7jzP+bl9i/wB6HdX7f6H/AOWGN/263+9L7jzP+bl9iveh3X/b3Qv/ACwxv+3W/wB6X3Hmf83L&#xA;7Fe9Du5jrvq3mWDIzupVPdrNfrBoDp5BDpgfmwrYhzeMcMMZ+xjvHI2S28XrvSaxZTd1LHeK3RVY&#xA;61suYQCNxnUtmJ7qDLyWc0RjlruKXRzRG5Yf84sCzIkdQxqaG2bGt3Me6wD6T3EuAY3w7p33DKI/&#xA;JImvs/iUe8Cd30pdA5DT6thV9RwX4drnNZYWyWOLTDXB3LQfBGMuE2osq/ZA3kDwAJOnm6ULRa5s&#xA;sa72u3NgzvBme0Q1K1WzFj3HaHCf6p/vSTarGAVPJ0hp0HwRG6DsmQSpJSklKSU0Ou4tGb0jKxMl&#xA;u+q2ste2SJEjuFDzOWWLEZR3DJgiJZAC8B/zJ+rX/cU/9uP/APJLH/0xzn734B0/uuPsr/mT9Wv+&#xA;4p/7cf8A+SS/0xzn734BX3XH2V/zJ+rX/cU/9uP/APJJf6Y5z978Ar7rj7K/5k/Vr/uKf+3H/wDk&#xA;kv8ATHOfvfgFfdcfZX/Mn6tf9xT/ANuP/wDJJf6Y5z978Ar7rj7K/wCZP1a/7in/ALcf/wCSS/0x&#xA;zn734BX3XH2V/wAyfq1/3FP/AG4//wAkl/pjnP3vwCvuuPs+nLechFkBpYA4lokaif8AvqSkI9Jr&#xA;XNa52umu935ZStVqioN2BzoJ1neT9/ISVazhUQG73bW+G8H7xqkq2Za1tTg10iCdSXH/AKWqQQdm&#xA;yklSSlJKUkpqdUdt6dkOiYYTHjCr84LwSZeX/nA8OzC6hkPGS7Psra5rXMZSBtkiTLXCInSFhnNi&#xA;gOHgB83U4JE3bcxLbLqZtAFrHOrs2/RLmHaS2ex5UGWIjLTbdfE2Gq7qriPVqbU2guLWPte4OsDd&#xA;C9rWMd7Z7lTDlhsbvw6LfcbWLksyqvUaIIO1zZBgjwI5BmQe4UOTGYGl8ZcQTJiVJKUkp7Fdc4KH&#xA;KIbWC4kAHkaHg+YSUhbk1sGzmO7tpP8A1aSl33ssqIa4B3gBrz5EpKQmj7XXUHPc0tHLfcTH7xHK&#xA;Skporx6Hhk8ckGfvKQ3Qdm4klSSlJKUkpq9TAOBeHcFhB+Crc7/MS8mXl/50PDYFOQ7GNBynsdS5&#xA;1VoaGkgtPLXES3c2CsTPOInfDvqHUgCRuk6caKsrJw8dzTU3ZbU1rt2jxtsO6TPvbr5lN5jilCM5&#xA;b6g/s/BMCASEXTnH7IyyrGNrNuyk+3dta50McXkaDsU7mB6yDKu6IbbJ8APbdkstayuwGsmuv6LG&#xA;lntaOPAymZ6MYkba7+a6G5bkFQL1JKUkp7Fdc4LWz/6OdQNRqRI/ikpp1mpp3C0NcP3a+PnokpOx&#xA;7X1u/SOsIGsiAASkplRBFZBB0MbdAf6vvSUkydMd5hw07n/akFHZsJKUkpSSlJKa3Uv6Dd/VVbnf&#xA;5iXkzct/Oh4c49R6jdReS6vLYLmMmGksDa7AY+DSsMTl7QkN46ftDqUOIg9Uz6aqMrFtra2toL6S&#xA;GgN/nANo0j85ijEzKEgfP7EkUQxxcVluHUbQQQ06Mc5oAJJ02kJ2TKY5DSoxsMsagU5GR6Zc47aw&#xA;0PJdEby0Sf6ybknxRjfj+xQFEtfFxRdj0Z+Nc9mS9odZY4lzbDw5lrJjnTTUKXLl4ZyhIen8vL+W&#xA;q2MbFg6tpuXtLWZTDQ9x2hx91bieNtg018DChOK9Ym/z+xfxd2wo1z2K65wWFtTbm7Hcc6R/GUlM&#xA;Bj7RtbY8AcAQB/1KSl/Qnmx5+Y/uSUu2kNj3OMef90JKU+ltjCxxdDhB1SUkSUpJSklKSU0OvOqb&#xA;0fLdc51bBUSXsMObHdp8QouYBOM0GTD84eEyb3upxb8kF1uJYH230xsLCNXc6F2ntWJjgBKQjtIa&#xA;A/y6d3TkTpboPqdnUbb2mlj4c0AxYPAnsPhqqwkMUtNT+DLXEEd2NTTttdbeXNArrrbYfcfANETP&#xA;dOhklLSh46IMQENFuTX1Qfa6TQ26osbbuDm2OBaWsMEw8Dd8QpJxgcPpN0du39i0E8eoTWtdgPa7&#xA;G91eTcA6kyYfZJc+uPhLm8d1HEjKPVvEb+XQpI4Dov1Kiq3BuN4BcK3Q4ToY00nx7IcvMxyCu6cg&#xA;BimLMn7F6e79Y9Lbu/4TbE/emXD3L/Rv8E0eF7ddW4aklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJTR64C7pOU0&#xA;N3k1kBvMnsoeZNYiyYP5wPJjFxMZm+wMZXSN2sNY0t5sPbd5lc57s5mhuf5U7HDGIYu6ljsaLbni&#xA;mt+rA8EPc3jft/Nae0ojl5E0BZ/BHuBr39Vwp315NdbjpvLTY8A/u/mhSw5XJsYk/gtlkj3ZjFOX&#xA;jVZOJZYHktuZ673Fji0y17mjx+SacntzMZAdtE8PFGwwGS7JyKL30vaKQ706yQGvud7ZY6YIDZiY&#xA;5R9sQiQDv+A8UWSbT57i/ptz7G+kQ3c0FwMkQ4CW+PCZgFZhWq6Z9Jbk/nQfGO/wUC97Fdc4KklK&#xA;SUxD2HhwPwKSl5HikpUjxSUrc0ckJKW3t8R96Slb2fvD70lMklNTqrWv6dex43Ncwgg9wVX5wkYJ&#xA;EMvLi8geLyLGV4D3n9KMVxDd53bn1mGb/GDz8FgwiZZQNuL9rqk+lwc93UMLBr6li0Nzs/KeH7bR&#xA;6jmMd9Fwpn3Od4/mjRaOAYsuQ45S4YR7aX9eg/Nr5OKMbAsr/WzIymdAoflRTmXV7bq6/wB4ge0c&#xA;8OKHwvHA8zLh1iDonmJEY9d3b6XZdkU1tcdteNXXU5vd9jWN37j5Ht96oczGMJHuST9GfHZCf3Yk&#xA;G7JcapA97BA7CXtAj4lR/wA5tHVd8vVqdWFYa+prXWX2MhriZh1jvTqY3sCXmfgCpuVvQ/o/w1Kz&#xA;JTpbbPT2hw9TbG+NN0fSj4qrYvbRk1p7Nda4SklKSU8fifW7CsudRj1vtraYFx9odHgOVMcd9WL3&#xA;COjp1fWLHgA1PJPYEaJvtFcMgLc/arHDd6RAiQ4kahD21e44fU/rhl9Oqde/p49IPbW1zrdHbg4z&#xA;o0/uoSjTJiHuGnkfrH9d+p9WxTjYod03k78e0y7+t7QY+BCbxcLOeVNbvO4PXbckU15RvyLWvaHP&#xA;fk2awedo0/FKUgxY4CT76ksafWDaOmZBoANmyGTxJ4UHN8PsyvZl5e/cDwvVCMXpNuJjtNh2ilu2&#xA;Z3v5JOvjJWJy3rziUvN1J6QoNB3WeqdP2YdOBfkitgZW80Wb+wAn6MR4wrA5TDmuRmB/hBj92UdA&#xA;LatXS+rdT6mzN60W12sHqU4u4O9FreLLGgwDJ9g8dTwppczgwYTDFqNjLv4D9qwQnOdy+x6jFxmY&#xA;lIpZrBLnE93HkrIy5DklZbcYiISua17SxwlrgQQeCDoQmA0UtNlQvzdxH6HBhlY/euLYLz/Uado+&#xA;JU5lwY/GW/l/axgXLybqgZHsV1zgqSUpJTwdH1cwOnu332tqcNSHWtmP6u2VLxnoxcHdtbOkMO/7&#xA;S8xz6bSR9+yEOKSeGKR+Z05gIGTbBH0TXoEOMp4A5f1rz8S36uWuxnmyXsEhkkQe/gPNCRuJZMMh&#xA;jm+eO9YsymvMWVs31M2mHAtlzS7s4A/NQXs3PdJEnM6OXNtaXaN9Rgn5hPm1sRq36YTmNo9bt9Hp&#xA;d90SKwHEcaBzSfwUPNR4sMh4MmDTIHjcVl92M0V2envc8uuEFzRvcCGTI3OIPu7Bc/kMYz1F+DrA&#xA;EhnXVTbigY4Oy36L3EuLx+++TLvEISnKM/VuP5UkAEaNOmmrGyM01Nl3qUY5DtSW+2x7ifg/nyU8&#xA;5ynGF9pH9iwAAl2DyqLMokAEuMAak+AHKSmvgEuxWWuEG4m0j+uS4fhCkz6TI7aLYbNhRrnsV1zg&#xA;qSUpJT4hhdSzKqw71iwnXdth+v7zolUZcxPYFdQCX9p5D3Hda466HUSeeJKYck1EqyrqsnE+z/aX&#xA;WZbiNzDvqFTSdP0juXeQaR5qxiFAEpAbl+T0inFsoqyrnXbK224xrY4O2neC61pa3aSOOU8Gwa6r&#xA;uEEi3lbr8g5bbcahzrvUdZa0F9gcHT7y0Q0cxG1PqPCt4p21eil7rmUkbmBzXcaAl0QmZgLtbrT9&#xA;JKZDV6m1r+n3seJa5hDge4PKr86SMEiGXl9cgeE6fZjM6a3ptjospa6m6tpkjaSHEnQAHxKxM8Zn&#xA;N7g2OodSBAjSezLc6onFLKamiDkug1saP3OAY+5RxxAS9Wp7dVxlpo0mOxbH13V5Ava4t9HKrIeL&#xA;TUdK7dum8AuH8oeYVgiYBBjXeJ6X1Hh+RYwQev1dlj2Ws9StwczncDI8eVRIMTRZrDmm+3qtjcdj&#xA;SzCfNllhMOtqaQGtaOQ2x0z/ACR5q1wRwDiPz9ux/s/Njsz8nT/BVGVSSnsV1zgqSUpJT4XjdA6+&#xA;36fS849vdj26fe1UskJnoklI/oH1icwuZg57COGjHtGg+FaUITGlJj5te36u/WjILPUwuoH0hDHD&#xA;HtmCZglzNVKAYjZMvNH/AM1PrSwkUYOWNx3O30Wak+exASPUFbZZ43QfrlRkeqzpmWx3pmpx9GyC&#xA;CZmQ3xTjVbFNm09X1X+sNNlT24GY4b27mmizTUTrsUQEj0XHbd9yVxjaPWzYOlZPpO9N+wgPjdtn&#xA;uG9yOwUPNV7UrDLg/nA8PmOOPitpO206DHxB7pJ4fbv1cZ8olYeIccydu8v4OnLQOUc/qz7r8d+W&#xA;W00Y1ry+prRutA2sY0uDpYHSPOFb9jAIxkI6mQ37fxYzKZJFun0PGxKelG/0W0syWC69jBDQ4N9+&#xA;1o4hzSYHCq85kySz1d1oP2MmKMRC6ZuwcXIv21U1va+ptgducz1PUnWwVloc2B4apozThHUnevKu&#xA;1pMQSm6QDZTZmPf6rsix+2yIaamEsrFbezIGn3pnNaSEQKofj1vxTi2tvKuyKSU9iuucFSSlJKUk&#xA;pSSlJKUkpSSlJKUkppda3fsvJ2TOzSI8f5UhQ81XsyZcH84HimY+H06l2VkuG943WWgHcdOGd++i&#xA;wJZMmaXDEeQdUAQFloYTW5VlWS5ppblzY6sgDbUHVisHkfnKzmJxgx34fz1tjjrr3bHTsxx6d066&#xA;iDVfc6u4EaODvU9w0/fAUefF+tyA7gWPwXQl6RTNtDcq+zCpJbiUgY9rmaS1kn0Gu/tQ7yHmmmfB&#xA;ETPzHUfxTXEaGzqNa1jQxgDWtADWgQABoAAqZJJZdlS0CSQB4ylRTRXkJIexXXOCpJSklKSUpJSk&#xA;lKSUpJSklKSU0+sPbX0zJsftDWVlxLztaI1lxPAUHNgnDIMvL6ZA+e5J+04uTl3FxbXVuYXS11jr&#xA;BFexv5lcn+sfLvkY/ROMR1P2Vv5n8HSkbBKsyp2PjPpoINra24tU+0AVhzrJ8OUsMhOYJ2viP12V&#xA;IUNE2CX4+BVjMAltYua5wBFTS5+50fyQNPNMzATymR715piajTp41NePQ2qoktEnc4yXFx3OcT4k&#xA;mVUyTM5WWWIACskluNaQCSGO0HPCWMXMea/GLmHBeZ6IxpIO24wJ1iCtID+knydEf7oPk3OqaMwa&#xA;N3cHd8mtlQcrvMsHLbzL6OuheVUkpSSlJKUkpSSlJKUkpSSlJKaXWvT/AGVkm1oextZcWkSDt93H&#xA;yUHNX7UqZcFe4Hgeqes/Ox7a3h2Jez1b28+3G/S/i7a38Fj8twjHIEeoaD/C0/i6U74h2Zmpr3+n&#xA;lODa8Wpgtnu+6bLNedGhNEiBcRrImvpoE77tlzKs+H0Vtc2GluS7TR0E7Gka6ePdRAyxbn6L9JbN&#xA;1rWsa1jBDWgNA8hoFXJJNrwKY3v9Oi1/7rHH8E6AuQC6AuQDzX2Vo6ecx7vcXitjR3/eJWt7h93g&#xA;Hm6nuH3eFu5r4zMepzd5ZS1hE6BzxofkSFXwx/VyPiwYh+rkfF9MW88kpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSk&#xA;lKSU0+rtc/puQ1kbizTd9Hngx2UHNkDDLyZeX/nA+cdPxvWyrTvc6kvZS1jxG0M/S3s059zWtnvC&#xA;y8+ThgNNd/2B0YRsujnP9PCyawf0t0B7v5d2gHyaquGPFkieg/YySNRIb9bBVWysaBjQ2BxoFXke&#xA;IksgFBkgpZ7d7HMmNwLZ+IhEGjaQaNtD9jg4TcM2O9rzZugTrpCsfe/1nHTY+9frOKkjOnNblPyC&#xA;8ndWKh4jQNn7gmnmCYCNdbWHPcBGutverp3m1JKWlJSpSUxdaxpAM6pKQO6hQ120h0/D/anCBIWm&#xA;YBYP6tjMklryG8kAR+VOGElacoDdUbIpJSklNHrl4xekZeSRPpVOfHiRrCh5mHuYjHuyYDWQF4bp&#xA;VdmPQcrLMBrDbYT3e/3H4wPxKw+akJy4Y+Tq4wQLLIVvssxGXA+rda7MtB12hg9rT8JaEDIASI2A&#xA;4QqrI+11FUZVJKY2tL6nsaYc5pAPgSEYmpApiaILgXWWt6VjuNjw8WWt+kZgLThGJzy00oOjGIOa&#xA;WnQNoXXP6ga/Ud6bKN2ydP5sfxKhMIjFda8X7WIwiMV1rf7X0hdA8opJTx/18+uOV9UMvpdtVTb6&#xA;MoZAvqJ2k7PQ2lrtYI3lA2kU2eh/Xz6v/WGjdXacW9v08e7Rw8wRoQhxBQjeza6h9Zui9NrFl1zn&#xA;/wDFtLyJ7mEuIJ4CuzqPSLMT9oMzKX47v8JvAaJ7GdZ8lLxsRgtRdjdRxhlYNjMih0hj6zLJaYI+&#xA;IT4yCyQLuqFmUkpSSnP+sEjo2W4VHILay4VNiXlpDg3XxhRZ/wCbOteLJh+cPGU5dHUKWVss300h&#xA;r8iwiJ2ahu2BG4tmPBYE8UsMia1OzrCQkGfTXuzLL+pvEC0+jQD2rrJk/wBp0/cm8wBjAxjpqfMq&#xA;h6iZN9V2RSSlTGp7apKeZpnJJpscfTYLbWDwMblrz9Go30Dqy9Go30DPp7HFuRaeBRYB5nbwm8wR&#xA;cR4hbnPyjxD6otl45SSny7/HcAf2LP8A3a/91kJEhT5rQ91Tg+txaRwWmCoySkGnTb1rMLNlrjYP&#xA;5XKYSycYYsyGXPFRlgce59s+JRGQgLTwl6j6r/Wir6r039Nybm3Y9j/XqdUJLXnRw1iQYTsWcTFk&#xA;ELCL2L7EpVKSUpJTW6l/Qbv6qrc7/MS8mblv50PHZXT8PMcLL2fpG8WNJa4fNv8AFc/iz5MYoHR1&#xA;pQEk1VTKKmU1Daytoa0eACjlIyJJSBQZoJUkpRAIIPB0KSnNr6e9nUXWhtfoOaWlgEANIgfk1VuX&#xA;MA4as22pZwcVa2tg4bqsXLoIBuMtPluZoJ+aWfMJTjLp/arNlEpxPT+19EXRvLqSU8d/jD+pvUvr&#xA;d9g/Z9lFf2P1t/2hz2z6vpRt2Vv/ANGmyBKnjR/ic+s4/wC1OB/25b/7zpvAVMh/if8ArOBH2rB/&#xA;7ct/950uAqU7/E99aDxlYP8A25b/AO86XAVMT/id+tER9pwP+3Lf/edLgKn2NSKUkpSSmt1L+g3f&#xA;1VW53+Yl5M3LfzoeXXNOwpJSklKSUpJSklKSU9iuucFSSlJKUkpSSlJKUkpSSlJKUkprdS/oN39V&#xA;Vud/mJeTNy386Hl1zTsKSUpJSklKSUpJSklPYrrnBUkpSSlJKUkpSSlJKUkpSSlJKYW1surdVYJa&#xA;4QRx+RNnCM4mJ2TGRibDW/ZHTv8ARf8ASd/5JVf9Hct+7+JZ/vebur9kdO/0X/Sd/wCSS/0dy37v&#xA;4lX3vN3V+yOnf6L/AKTv/JJf6O5b938Sr73m7q/ZHTv9F/0nf+SS/wBHct+7+JV97zd1fsjp3+i/&#xA;6Tv/ACSX+juW/d/Eq+95u6v2R07/AEX/AEnf+SS/0dy37v4lX3vN3V+yOnf6L/pO/wDJJf6O5b93&#xA;8Sr73m7txXGupJSklI7bqqdvqu273bW+bj2H3JKULmHgO/zHf3JKV6zPB/8AmO/uSUz3CN3A89El&#xA;Lb2cSElLgg8GUlLpKUkpSSlJKUkpSSlJKUkpSSlJKUkpSSmpn49N4pNzBYabBbXIBh4DgHcHiUQS&#xA;FM26N1EjnUxH3NCClqnPI1c4Dtx4/wBUJKZstbtLyXEfygAkpdtrHg+0j4iElMmlu6GiNNUlM0lK&#xA;SUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSDJc5rW7TEnX/WQkpG25rjBc5vmX/wB0pKZtc1x9jy4jWA4n&#xA;/vqSmD77ha6trgNrS7UT2+R/BJTJv2vaJsaT4hhj+KSklZfvh5khvhHf4BJSVJSklKSUpJSklKSU&#xA;pJSklKSUpJSklKSU1s0w1nu2y6Ne/ly1JSDXxP3/APmaSlSY5P8Ar/aSUoCLXjUfo5gmf7/yfNJT&#xA;ZaPaNOw7f+YlJS9elp/q+Ed/gElJklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSHIY54btEwdf9ZCSk&#xA;TMd5PvBA+MfkLklJhVAiB+H/AJFJSF2PYbnuDfaWQOOf9fJJSVtR2iQOPL/yJSUuxhbYTGm2NI8f&#xA;gElJUlKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJS&#xA;klKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJSklKS&#xA;UpJSklKSUpJSklKSUpJT/9k=</xmpGImg:image>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </xmp:PageInfo>
         <xmpMM:InstanceID>xmp.iid:73585586-53e2-4949-9f7e-6082b21a6b6f</xmpMM:InstanceID>
         <xmpMM:DocumentID>xmp.did:07a9a7cc-7a07-2246-8e05-48bafeb158ec</xmpMM:DocumentID>
         <xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID>xmp.did:07a9a7cc-7a07-2246-8e05-48bafeb158ec</xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID>
         <xmpMM:History>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>created</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:07a9a7cc-7a07-2246-8e05-48bafeb158ec</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2020-12-08T11:45:46+05:30</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe InDesign 16.0 (Windows)</stEvt:softwareAgent>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:455c41f0-2c49-5048-95e8-b596a61ac06f</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2020-12-08T12:25:37+05:30</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe InDesign 16.0 (Windows)</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:ad8819ac-ec78-374b-8271-09130352ff65</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2020-12-08T12:25:37+05:30</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe InDesign 16.0 (Windows)</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/metadata</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:ee771fd0-3139-f944-908a-8ef3fce53753</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2020-12-08T12:30:29+05:30</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe InDesign 16.0 (Windows)</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:73585586-53e2-4949-9f7e-6082b21a6b6f</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2020-12-22T12:13:16+05:30</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe InDesign 16.1 (Windows)</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </xmpMM:History>
         <xmpMM:RenditionClass>default</xmpMM:RenditionClass>
         <xmpMM:Manifest>
            <rdf:Bag>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stMfs:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stMfs:linkForm>
                  <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
                     <stRef:lastURL>http://serverpath/abc.psd</stRef:lastURL>
                  </stMfs:reference>
                  <xmpMM:placedXResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedXResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedYResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedYResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stMfs:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stMfs:linkForm>
                  <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
                     <stRef:lastURL>http://serverpath/abc.jpg</stRef:lastURL>
                  </stMfs:reference>
                  <xmpMM:placedXResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedXResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedYResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedYResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stMfs:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stMfs:linkForm>
                  <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
                     <stRef:lastURL>http://serverpath/abc.indd</stRef:lastURL>
                  </stMfs:reference>
                  <xmpMM:placedXResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedXResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedYResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedYResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stMfs:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stMfs:linkForm>
                  <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
                     <stRef:lastURL>http://serverpath/abc.png</stRef:lastURL>
                  </stMfs:reference>
                  <xmpMM:placedXResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedXResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedYResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedYResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stMfs:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stMfs:linkForm>
                  <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
                     <stRef:instanceID>xmp.iid:45d0e558-56ba-4d54-9b4e-842e56a27460</stRef:instanceID>
                     <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:6fa23242-08de-4c1a-b9c8-97b4ab533a00</stRef:documentID>
                     <stRef:lastURL>http://serverpath/abc1.psd</stRef:lastURL>
                  </stMfs:reference>
                  <xmpMM:placedXResolution>300.00</xmpMM:placedXResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedYResolution>300.00</xmpMM:placedYResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stMfs:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stMfs:linkForm>
                  <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
                     <stRef:lastURL>http://serverpath/abc123.psd</stRef:lastURL>
                  </stMfs:reference>
                  <xmpMM:placedXResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedXResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedYResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedYResolution>
                  <xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Bag>
         </xmpMM:Manifest>
         <xmpMM:Ingredients>
            <rdf:Bag>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stRef:instanceID>xmp.iid:00a4ff1f-df49-734e-ba96-0714724feadf</stRef:instanceID>
                  <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:00a4ff1f-df49-734e-ba96-0714724feadf</stRef:documentID>
                  <stRef:fromPart>/</stRef:fromPart>
                  <stRef:toPart>/</stRef:toPart>
                  <stRef:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stRef:linkForm>
                  <stRef:linkCategory>Content</stRef:linkCategory>
                  <stRef:filePath>http://serverpath/abc123.psd</stRef:filePath>
                  <stRef:placedXResolution>72.00</stRef:placedXResolution>
                  <stRef:placedYResolution>72.00</stRef:placedYResolution>
                  <stRef:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</stRef:placedResolutionUnit>
                  <stRef:maskMarkers>None</stRef:maskMarkers>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stRef:instanceID>xmp.iid:6d143f21-f207-de43-9e2d-f9464dbb6292</stRef:instanceID>
                  <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:6d143f21-f207-de43-9e2d-f9464dbb6292</stRef:documentID>
                  <stRef:fromPart>/</stRef:fromPart>
                  <stRef:toPart>/</stRef:toPart>
                  <stRef:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stRef:linkForm>
                  <stRef:linkCategory>Content</stRef:linkCategory>
                  <stRef:filePath>http://serverpath/abc12.psd</stRef:filePath>
                  <stRef:placedXResolution>300.00</stRef:placedXResolution>
                  <stRef:placedYResolution>300.00</stRef:placedYResolution>
                  <stRef:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</stRef:placedResolutionUnit>
                  <stRef:maskMarkers>None</stRef:maskMarkers>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stRef:instanceID>xmp.iid:ab277e52-2f6d-3f4e-a3b9-b75cb636040b</stRef:instanceID>
                  <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:ab277e52-2f6d-3f4e-a3b9-b75cb636040b</stRef:documentID>
                  <stRef:fromPart>/</stRef:fromPart>
                  <stRef:toPart>/</stRef:toPart>
                  <stRef:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stRef:linkForm>
                  <stRef:linkCategory>Content</stRef:linkCategory>
                  <stRef:filePath>http://serverpath/abc123.jpg</stRef:filePath>
                  <stRef:placedXResolution>72.00</stRef:placedXResolution>
                  <stRef:placedYResolution>72.00</stRef:placedYResolution>
                  <stRef:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</stRef:placedResolutionUnit>
                  <stRef:maskMarkers>None</stRef:maskMarkers>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stRef:instanceID>xmp.iid:ad7566ec-121c-8a4d-a2c1-fde2a4b4d638</stRef:instanceID>
                  <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:ad7566ec-121c-8a4d-a2c1-fde2a4b4d638</stRef:documentID>
                  <stRef:fromPart>/</stRef:fromPart>
                  <stRef:toPart>/</stRef:toPart>
                  <stRef:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stRef:linkForm>
                  <stRef:linkCategory>Content</stRef:linkCategory>
                  <stRef:filePath>http://serverpath/abc1123.psd</stRef:filePath>
                  <stRef:placedXResolution>72.00</stRef:placedXResolution>
                  <stRef:placedYResolution>72.00</stRef:placedYResolution>
                  <stRef:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</stRef:placedResolutionUnit>
                  <stRef:maskMarkers>None</stRef:maskMarkers>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stRef:instanceID>xmp.iid:e8c61cfd-a25b-504c-b14f-adc3439a9a7c</stRef:instanceID>
                  <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:e8c61cfd-a25b-504c-b14f-adc3439a9a7c</stRef:documentID>
                  <stRef:fromPart>/</stRef:fromPart>
                  <stRef:toPart>/</stRef:toPart>
                  <stRef:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stRef:linkForm>
                  <stRef:linkCategory>Content</stRef:linkCategory>
                  <stRef:filePath>http://serverpath/abc123_345.psd</stRef:filePath>
                  <stRef:placedXResolution>72.00</stRef:placedXResolution>
                  <stRef:placedYResolution>72.00</stRef:placedYResolution>
                  <stRef:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</stRef:placedResolutionUnit>
                  <stRef:maskMarkers>None</stRef:maskMarkers>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stRef:instanceID>xmp.iid:f586dead-3831-0d4f-a94b-866e7b20c66b</stRef:instanceID>
                  <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:f586dead-3831-0d4f-a94b-866e7b20c66b</stRef:documentID>
                  <stRef:fromPart>/</stRef:fromPart>
                  <stRef:toPart>/</stRef:toPart>
                  <stRef:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stRef:linkForm>
                  <stRef:linkCategory>Content</stRef:linkCategory>
                  <stRef:filePath>http://serverpath/abc123_09.indd</stRef:filePath>
                  <stRef:placedXResolution>72.00</stRef:placedXResolution>
                  <stRef:placedYResolution>72.00</stRef:placedYResolution>
                  <stRef:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</stRef:placedResolutionUnit>
                  <stRef:maskMarkers>None</stRef:maskMarkers>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Bag>
         </xmpMM:Ingredients>
         <idPriv:DocChangeCount>1</idPriv:DocChangeCount>
         <idPriv:keyStampMp>AAAAAA==</idPriv:keyStampMp>
         <xmpTPg:Colorants>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <xmpG:swatchName>Black</xmpG:swatchName>
                  <xmpG:mode>RGB</xmpG:mode>
                  <xmpG:type>Process</xmpG:type>
                  <xmpG:red>0</xmpG:red>
                  <xmpG:green>0</xmpG:green>
                  <xmpG:blue>0</xmpG:blue>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <xmpG:swatchName>Paper</xmpG:swatchName>
                  <xmpG:mode>CMYK</xmpG:mode>
                  <xmpG:type>Process</xmpG:type>
                  <xmpG:cyan>0</xmpG:cyan>
                  <xmpG:magenta>0</xmpG:magenta>
                  <xmpG:yellow>0</xmpG:yellow>
                  <xmpG:black>0</xmpG:black>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <xmpG:swatchName>Registration</xmpG:swatchName>
                  <xmpG:mode>CMYK</xmpG:mode>
                  <xmpG:type>Process</xmpG:type>
                  <xmpG:cyan>100</xmpG:cyan>
                  <xmpG:magenta>100</xmpG:magenta>
                  <xmpG:yellow>100</xmpG:yellow>
                  <xmpG:black>100</xmpG:black>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </xmpTPg:Colorants>
         <xmpTPg:Fonts>
            <rdf:Bag>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stFnt:fontName>MinionPro-Regular</stFnt:fontName>
                  <stFnt:fontFamily>Minion Pro</stFnt:fontFamily>
                  <stFnt:fontFace>Regular</stFnt:fontFace>
                  <stFnt:fontType>OpenTypeCFF</stFnt:fontType>
                  <stFnt:versionString>MinionPro-RegularVersion 2.112;PS 2.000;hotconv 1.0.70;makeotf.lib2.5.5900</stFnt:versionString>
                  <stFnt:composite>false</stFnt:composite>
                  <stFnt:fontFileName>MinionPro-Regular.otf</stFnt:fontFileName>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Bag>
         </xmpTPg:Fonts>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>                                                                                            
                           
<?xpacket end="w"?>
```

I want to extract the data of `stRef:lastURL` and `stRef:filePath` from above xml, i have tried with

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('C:\\tmp.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)

namespaces = {'stRef': 'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#'}

for node in tree.findall('stRef:lastURL', namespaces):
     print(node)
```

but its not giving me any required data, can someone please help, how can get the data from the file

Comment: @larsks </xmpGImg:image> is present in the end of <xmpGImg:image> line so the xml looks ok

Comment: Hah, might have been a copy and paste error on my part then! Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `findall` method only searches for elements that are *direct children* of the current element:

> Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element. Element.find() finds the first child with a particular tag, and Element.text accesses the element’s text content. Element.get() accesses the element’s attributes... (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements)

However, it also has [limited support for XPath expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath), so you can write this instead:

```
for node in tree.findall('.//stRef:lastURL', namespaces):
    print(node)
```

Which will cause your code to print:

```
<Element '{http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#}lastURL' at 0x7f48e8e91360>
<Element '{http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#}lastURL' at 0x7f48e8e915e0>
<Element '{http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#}lastURL' at 0x7f48e8e91860>
<Element '{http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#}lastURL' at 0x7f48e8e91ae0>
<Element '{http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#}lastURL' at 0x7f48e8e91e00>
<Element '{http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#}lastURL' at 0x7f48e8e940e0>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer